Good tutorials for interest rate curve construction
Currently reading the "Pricing and Trading Interest Rate Derivatives" and I'm currently in the single currency curve modeling chapter and I want to see this how this is done in reality so if someone has a good video tutorial covering this I would really appreciate it!

This isn't really a question so it will likely be closed by community, but I have provided an answer to point you in the right direction anyway. Another tutorial which goes through building curves for the library QuantLib is available here: https://www.implementingquantlib.com/2023/09/ametrano-bianchetti.html

If you look at the Rateslib Channel for rateslib-excel, it hosts a (currently silent) demonstration of building a Curve in Excel from US SOFR rates.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16u8Oa1dF2M
How does this relate to the Single Currency Curve Modelling section in you question. It demonstrates design requirements that are listed in those principles:

Time syncronised: all data is obtained from a single source using the Bloomberg fetch data function.
Calibrated to market instruments: all the instruments which the curve needs to reprice are setup.
Numerically efficient. In the video, market updates are taking about 150ms to reiterate the curve.
Practically maintainable and transparent: the curve is a very simple structure and all info is visible.
Means of hedging: the video shows how delta risk for an arbitrary swap is calculated - those are the market hedges.
Inherent structure: this is not required because the curve is calculated from external data and not internally generated data.
Useful for market analysis: the tenor points on this curve are static so, particularly for tenors beyond about 6m you can build up good historical data base with this curve.
Robust to the passage of time: yes in some ways, no in others.

Your book also has a chapter on Advanced Curve Building, which considers other design styles which are more complicated but, for a market maker, can provide better risk representations and be better aligned with the market in terms of central bank meeting periods.
But what design features you employ depends upon your intended use. I have worked at organisations whose risk department, valuation department and trading department build different curve because they all have different purposes and objectives.
